# Record an audio stream with WASAPI

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, audio, wasapi

I'm reading documentation such as [Capturing a stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/capturing-a-stream) or [Loopback recording](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/loopback-recording), but I can't find a good reproducible example (with includes, build instructions, etc.) about how to record chunks from a Loopback audio device (sometimes called "What you hear", "Stereo Mix") with Windows WASAPI.

**Would you have a simple reproducible example showing how to record audio chunks in a loop from a WASAPI device, in C++?**

Here is a similar (working) example in Python:

```
import soundcard as sc  # installed with: pip install soundcard
lb = sc.all_microphones(include_loopback=True)[0]
with lb.recorder(samplerate=44100) as mic:
    while True:
        data = mic.record(numframes=None)
        print(data)    # chunks of audio data (448 samples x 2 channels as an array by default)
```

Comment: "*In the code example in Capturing a Stream, the RecordAudioStream function can be easily modified to configure a loopback-mode capture stream.*" Have you followed [this part instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/loopback-recording) to see if it helps?

Comment: I have seen this @RitaHan-MSFT, but I even don't achieve to compile the original code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/capturing-a-stream: there is no include, no build instructions, etc. These details are not really obvious in this case. If I can first achieve to build this, then, yes I think I will be able to adapt to *"loopback-mode capture"*.

Comment: Please check this blog for more detailed information: [Sample - WASAPI loopback capture (record what you hear).](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/matthew_van_eerde/sample-wasapi-loopback-capture-record-what-you-hear)

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Do you mean https://github.com/mvaneerde/blog/tree/develop/loopback-capture/loopback-capture? It looks promising, but it's split among many cpp files, not very easy to understand, but I'll study this, you're right. The best would be to have an updated MSDN page here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/capturing-a-stream with a reproducible code (with build instructions, includes, headers, etc.)

Comment: It contains a VS solution file, it is easy to build and run using Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes @RitaHan-MSFT, but I mean a simpler example (using only basic features) in a single .cpp + .h file would be better to start with. Here it's already quite complex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an example of **loopback-mode audio capturing**.

Based on documents [Capturing a stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/capturing-a-stream), make some editions pointed out by [Loopback recording](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/loopback-recording) as follows:

```
// In the call to the IMMDeviceEnumerator::GetDefaultAudioEndpoint method, change the first parameter (dataFlow) from eCapture to eRender.
hr = pEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(
    eRender, eConsole, &pDevice);

...

// In the call to the IAudioClient::Initialize method, change the value of the second parameter (StreamFlags) from 0 to AUDCLNT_STREAMFLAGS_LOOPBACK.
hr = pAudioClient->Initialize(
    AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED,
    AUDCLNT_STREAMFLAGS_LOOPBACK,
    hnsRequestedDuration,
    0,
    pwfx,
    NULL);
```

Missed part in the documents: `CopyData()` and write file functions (`WriteWaveHeader()` and `FinishWaveFile()`). The following show examples for those functions implementations. Refer to blog [Sample - WASAPI loopback capture (record what you hear)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/matthew_van_eerde/sample-wasapi-loopback-capture-record-what-you-hear) for more detailed information.

```
HRESULT MyAudioSink::CopyData(BYTE* pData, UINT32 NumFrames, BOOL* pDone, WAVEFORMATEX* pwfx, HMMIO hFile)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    if (0 == NumFrames) {
        wprintf(L"IAudioCaptureClient::GetBuffer said to read 0 frames\n");
        return E_UNEXPECTED;
    }

    LONG lBytesToWrite = NumFrames * pwfx->nBlockAlign;
#pragma prefast(suppress: __WARNING_INCORRECT_ANNOTATION, "IAudioCaptureClient::GetBuffer SAL annotation implies a 1-byte buffer")
    LONG lBytesWritten = mmioWrite(hFile, reinterpret_cast<PCHAR>(pData), lBytesToWrite);
    if (lBytesToWrite != lBytesWritten) {
        wprintf(L"mmioWrite wrote %u bytes : expected %u bytes", lBytesWritten, lBytesToWrite);
        return E_UNEXPECTED;
    }

    static int CallCount = 0;
    cout << "CallCount = " << CallCount++ << "NumFrames: " << NumFrames << endl ;

    if (clock() > 10 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC) //Record 10 seconds. From the first time call clock() at the beginning of the main().
        *pDone = true;

    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT WriteWaveHeader(HMMIO hFile, LPCWAVEFORMATEX pwfx, MMCKINFO* pckRIFF, MMCKINFO* pckData) {
    MMRESULT result;

    // make a RIFF/WAVE chunk
    pckRIFF->ckid = MAKEFOURCC('R', 'I', 'F', 'F');
    pckRIFF->fccType = MAKEFOURCC('W', 'A', 'V', 'E');

    result = mmioCreateChunk(hFile, pckRIFF, MMIO_CREATERIFF);
    if (MMSYSERR_NOERROR != result) {
        wprintf(L"mmioCreateChunk(\"RIFF/WAVE\") failed: MMRESULT = 0x%08x", result);
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    // make a 'fmt ' chunk (within the RIFF/WAVE chunk)
    MMCKINFO chunk;
    chunk.ckid = MAKEFOURCC('f', 'm', 't', ' ');
    result = mmioCreateChunk(hFile, &chunk, 0);
    if (MMSYSERR_NOERROR != result) {
        wprintf(L"mmioCreateChunk(\"fmt \") failed: MMRESULT = 0x%08x", result);
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    // write the WAVEFORMATEX data to it
    LONG lBytesInWfx = sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX) + pwfx->cbSize;
    LONG lBytesWritten =
        mmioWrite(
            hFile,
            reinterpret_cast<PCHAR>(const_cast<LPWAVEFORMATEX>(pwfx)),
            lBytesInWfx
        );
    if (lBytesWritten != lBytesInWfx) {
        wprintf(L"mmioWrite(fmt data) wrote %u bytes; expected %u bytes", lBytesWritten, lBytesInWfx);
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    // ascend from the 'fmt ' chunk
    result = mmioAscend(hFile, &chunk, 0);
    if (MMSYSERR_NOERROR != result) {
        wprintf(L"mmioAscend(\"fmt \" failed: MMRESULT = 0x%08x", result);
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    // make a 'fact' chunk whose data is (DWORD)0
    chunk.ckid = MAKEFOURCC('f', 'a', 'c', 't');
    result = mmioCreateChunk(hFile, &chunk, 0);
    if (MMSYSERR_NOERROR != result) {
        wprintf(L"mmioCreateChunk(\"fmt \") failed: MMRESULT = 0x%08x", result);
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    // write (DWORD)0 to it
    // this is cleaned up later
    DWORD frames = 0;
    lBytesWritten = mmioWrite(hFile, reinterpret_cast<PCHAR>(&frames), sizeof(frames));
    if (lBytesWritten != sizeof(frames)) {
        wprintf(L"mmioWrite(fact data) wrote %u bytes; expected %u bytes", lBytesWritten, (UINT32)sizeof(frames));
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    // ascend from the 'fact' chunk
    result = mmioAscend(hFile, &chunk, 0);
    if (MMSYSERR_NOERROR != result) {
        wprintf(L"mmioAscend(\"fact\" failed: MMRESULT = 0x%08x", result);
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    // make a 'data' chunk and leave the data pointer there
    pckData->ckid = MAKEFOURCC('d', 'a', 't', 'a');
    result = mmioCreateChunk(hFile, pckData, 0);
    if (MMSYSERR_NOERROR != result) {
        wprintf(L"mmioCreateChunk(\"data\") failed: MMRESULT = 0x%08x", result);
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT FinishWaveFile(HMMIO hFile, MMCKINFO* pckRIFF, MMCKINFO* pckData) {
    MMRESULT result;

    result = mmioAscend(hFile, pckData, 0);
    if (MMSYSERR_NOERROR != result) {
        wprintf(L"mmioAscend(\"data\" failed: MMRESULT = 0x%08x", result);
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    result = mmioAscend(hFile, pckRIFF, 0);
    if (MMSYSERR_NOERROR != result) {
        wprintf(L"mmioAscend(\"RIFF/WAVE\" failed: MMRESULT = 0x%08x", result);
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    return S_OK;
}
```

Call `WriteWaveHeader` before `pAudioClient->Start()`. Call `FinishWaveFile` after `pAudioClient->Stop()`.

As a result, it will record about 10 seconds audio playing on your Windows.

**UPDATE #1:**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>
#include <audioclient.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    clock();

    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

    // Create file
    MMIOINFO mi = { 0 };
    hFile = mmioOpen(
        // some flags cause mmioOpen write to this buffer
        // but not any that we're using
        (LPWSTR)fileName,
        &mi,
        MMIO_WRITE | MMIO_CREATE
    );

    if (NULL == hFile) {
        wprintf(L"mmioOpen(\"%ls\", ...) failed. wErrorRet == %u", fileName, GetLastError());
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    MyAudioSink AudioSink;
    RecordAudioStream(&AudioSink);

    mmioClose(hFile, 0);

    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile command:

```
cl -DUNICODE loopbackCapture.cpp /link winmm.lib user32.lib Kernel32.lib Ole32.lib
```

**UPDATE #2:**

```
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <mmsystem.h>
    #include <mmdeviceapi.h>
    #include <audioclient.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <iostream>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    #pragma comment(lib, "Winmm.lib")
    
    WCHAR fileName[] = L"loopback-capture.wav";
    BOOL bDone = FALSE;
    HMMIO hFile = NULL;
    
    // REFERENCE_TIME time units per second and per millisecond
    #define REFTIMES_PER_SEC  10000000
    #define REFTIMES_PER_MILLISEC  10000
    
    #define EXIT_ON_ERROR(hres)  \
                  if (FAILED(hres)) { goto Exit; }
    #define SAFE_RELEASE(punk)  \
                  if ((punk) != NULL)  \
                    { (punk)->Release(); (punk) = NULL; }
    
    const CLSID CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator);
    const IID IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator);
    const IID IID_IAudioClient = __uuidof(IAudioClient);
    const IID IID_IAudioCaptureClient = __uuidof(IAudioCaptureClient);
    
    class MyAudioSink
    {
    public:
        HRESULT CopyData(BYTE* pData, UINT32 NumFrames, BOOL* pDone, WAVEFORMATEX* pwfx, HMMIO hFile);
    };
    
    HRESULT WriteWaveHeader(HMMIO hFile, LPCWAVEFORMATEX pwfx, MMCKINFO* pckRIFF, MMCKINFO* pckData);
    HRESULT FinishWaveFile(HMMIO hFile, MMCKINFO* pckRIFF, MMCKINFO* pckData);
    HRESULT RecordAudioStream(MyAudioSink* pMySink);
    
    int main()
    {
        clock();
    
        HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    
        // Create file
        MMIOINFO mi = { 0 };
        hFile = mmioOpen(
            // some flags cause mmioOpen write to this buffer
            // but not any that we're using
            (LPWSTR)fileName,
            &mi,
            MMIO_WRITE | MMIO_CREATE
        );
    
        if (NULL == hFile) {
            wprintf(L"mmioOpen(\"%ls\", ...) failed. wErrorRet == %u", fileName, GetLastError());
            return E_FAIL;
        }
    
        MyAudioSink AudioSink;
        RecordAudioStream(&AudioSink);
    
        mmioClose(hFile, 0);
    
        CoUninitialize();
        return 0;
    }
    
    
    HRESULT MyAudioSink::CopyData(BYTE* pData, UINT32 NumFrames, BOOL* pDone, WAVEFORMATEX* pwfx, HMMIO hFile)
    {
        HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    
        if (0 == NumFrames) {
            wprintf(L"IAudioCaptureClient::GetBuffer said to read 0 frames\n");
            return E_UNEXPECTED;
        }
    
        LONG lBytesToWrite = NumFrames * pwfx->nBlockAlign;
    #pragma prefast(suppress: __WARNING_INCORRECT_ANNOTATION, "IAudioCaptureClient::GetBuffer SAL annotation implies a 1-byte buffer")
        LONG lBytesWritten = mmioWrite(hFile, reinterpret_cast<PCHAR>(pData), lBytesToWrite);
        if (lBytesToWrite != lBytesWritten) {
            wprintf(L"mmioWrite wrote %u bytes : expected %u bytes", lBytesWritten, lBytesToWrite);
            return E_UNEXPECTED;
        }
    
        static int CallCount = 0;
        cout << "CallCount = " << CallCount++ << "NumFrames: " << NumFrames << endl ;
    
        if (clock() > 10 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC) //Record 10 seconds. From the first time call clock() at the beginning of the main().
            *pDone = true;
    
        return S_OK;
    }
    
    HRESULT RecordAudioStream(MyAudioSink* pMySink)
    {
        HRESULT hr;
        REFERENCE_TIME hnsRequestedDuration = REFTIMES_PER_SEC;
        REFERENCE_TIME hnsActualDuration;
        UINT32 bufferFrameCount;
        UINT32 numFramesAvailable;
        IMMDeviceEnumerator* pEnumerator = NULL;
        IMMDevice* pDevice = NULL;
        IAudioClient* pAudioClient = NULL;
        IAudioCaptureClient* pCaptureClient = NULL;
        WAVEFORMATEX* pwfx = NULL;
        UINT32 packetLength = 0;
    
        BYTE* pData;
        DWORD flags;
    
        MMCKINFO ckRIFF = { 0 };
        MMCKINFO ckData = { 0 };
    
        hr = CoCreateInstance(
            CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, NULL,
            CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator,
            (void**)& pEnumerator);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)
    
        hr = pEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(
            eRender, eConsole, &pDevice);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)
    
        hr = pDevice->Activate(
            IID_IAudioClient, CLSCTX_ALL,
            NULL, (void**)& pAudioClient);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)
    
        hr = pAudioClient->GetMixFormat(&pwfx);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)
    
        hr = pAudioClient->Initialize(
            AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED,
            AUDCLNT_STREAMFLAGS_LOOPBACK,
            hnsRequestedDuration,
            0,
            pwfx,
            NULL);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)
    
        // Get the size of the allocated buffer.
        hr = pAudioClient->GetBufferSize(&bufferFrameCount);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)
    
        hr = pAudioClient->GetService(
            IID_IAudioCaptureClient,
            (void**)& pCaptureClient);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)
    
        hr = WriteWaveHeader((HMMIO)hFile, pwfx, &ckRIFF, &ckData);
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            // WriteWaveHeader does its own logging
            return hr;
        }
    
        // Calculate the actual duration of the allocated buffer.
        hnsActualDuration = (double)REFTIMES_PER_SEC *
        bufferFrameCount / pwfx->nSamplesPerSec;
    
        hr = pAudioClient->Start();  // Start recording.
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)
    
        // Each loop fills about half of the shared buffer.
        while (bDone == FALSE)
        {
            // Sleep for half the buffer duration.
            Sleep(hnsActualDuration / REFTIMES_PER_MILLISEC / 2);
    
            hr = pCaptureClient->GetNextPacketSize(&packetLength);
            EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)
    
            while (packetLength != 0)
            {
                // Get the available data in the shared buffer.
                hr = pCaptureClient->GetBuffer(
                    &pData,
                    &numFramesAvailable,
                    &flags, NULL, NULL);
                EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)
    
                    if (flags & AUDCLNT_BUFFERFLAGS_SILENT)
                    {
                        pData = NULL;  // Tell CopyData to write silence.
                    }
    
                // Copy the available capture data to the audio sink.
                hr = pMySink->CopyData(
                    pData, numFramesAvailable, &bDone, pwfx, (HMMIO)hFile);
                EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)
    
                    hr = pCaptureClient->ReleaseBuffer(numFramesAvailable);
                EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)
    
                    hr = pCaptureClient->GetNextPacketSize(&packetLength);
                EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)
            }
        }
    
        hr = pAudioClient->Stop();  // Stop recording.
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)
    
        hr = FinishWaveFile((HMMIO)hFile, &ckData, &ckRIFF);
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            // FinishWaveFile does it's own logging
            return hr;
        }
    
    Exit:
        CoTaskMemFree(pwfx);
        SAFE_RELEASE(pEnumerator)
        SAFE_RELEASE(pDevice)
        SAFE_RELEASE(pAudioClient)
        SAFE_RELEASE(pCaptureClient)
    
        return hr;
    }

HRESULT WriteWaveHeader(HMMIO hFile, LPCWAVEFORMATEX pwfx, MMCKINFO* pckRIFF, MMCKINFO* pckData) {
    MMRESULT result;

    // make a RIFF/WAVE chunk
    pckRIFF->ckid = MAKEFOURCC('R', 'I', 'F', 'F');
    pckRIFF->fccType = MAKEFOURCC('W', 'A', 'V', 'E');

    result = mmioCreateChunk(hFile, pckRIFF, MMIO_CREATERIFF);
    if (MMSYSERR_NOERROR != result) {
        wprintf(L"mmioCreateChunk(\"RIFF/WAVE\") failed: MMRESULT = 0x%08x", result);
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    // make a 'fmt ' chunk (within the RIFF/WAVE chunk)
    MMCKINFO chunk;
    chunk.ckid = MAKEFOURCC('f', 'm', 't', ' ');
    result = mmioCreateChunk(hFile, &chunk, 0);
    if (MMSYSERR_NOERROR != result) {
        wprintf(L"mmioCreateChunk(\"fmt \") failed: MMRESULT = 0x%08x", result);
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    // write the WAVEFORMATEX data to it
    LONG lBytesInWfx = sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX) + pwfx->cbSize;
    LONG lBytesWritten =
        mmioWrite(
            hFile,
            reinterpret_cast<PCHAR>(const_cast<LPWAVEFORMATEX>(pwfx)),
            lBytesInWfx
        );
    if (lBytesWritten != lBytesInWfx) {
        wprintf(L"mmioWrite(fmt data) wrote %u bytes; expected %u bytes", lBytesWritten, lBytesInWfx);
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    // ascend from the 'fmt ' chunk
    result = mmioAscend(hFile, &chunk, 0);
    if (MMSYSERR_NOERROR != result) {
        wprintf(L"mmioAscend(\"fmt \" failed: MMRESULT = 0x%08x", result);
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    // make a 'fact' chunk whose data is (DWORD)0
    chunk.ckid = MAKEFOURCC('f', 'a', 'c', 't');
    result = mmioCreateChunk(hFile, &chunk, 0);
    if (MMSYSERR_NOERROR != result) {
        wprintf(L"mmioCreateChunk(\"fmt \") failed: MMRESULT = 0x%08x", result);
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    // write (DWORD)0 to it
    // this is cleaned up later
    DWORD frames = 0;
    lBytesWritten = mmioWrite(hFile, reinterpret_cast<PCHAR>(&frames), sizeof(frames));
    if (lBytesWritten != sizeof(frames)) {
        wprintf(L"mmioWrite(fact data) wrote %u bytes; expected %u bytes", lBytesWritten, (UINT32)sizeof(frames));
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    // ascend from the 'fact' chunk
    result = mmioAscend(hFile, &chunk, 0);
    if (MMSYSERR_NOERROR != result) {
        wprintf(L"mmioAscend(\"fact\" failed: MMRESULT = 0x%08x", result);
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    // make a 'data' chunk and leave the data pointer there
    pckData->ckid = MAKEFOURCC('d', 'a', 't', 'a');
    result = mmioCreateChunk(hFile, pckData, 0);
    if (MMSYSERR_NOERROR != result) {
        wprintf(L"mmioCreateChunk(\"data\") failed: MMRESULT = 0x%08x", result);
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT FinishWaveFile(HMMIO hFile, MMCKINFO* pckRIFF, MMCKINFO* pckData) {
    MMRESULT result;

    result = mmioAscend(hFile, pckData, 0);
    if (MMSYSERR_NOERROR != result) {
        wprintf(L"mmioAscend(\"data\" failed: MMRESULT = 0x%08x", result);
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    result = mmioAscend(hFile, pckRIFF, 0);
    if (MMSYSERR_NOERROR != result) {
        wprintf(L"mmioAscend(\"RIFF/WAVE\" failed: MMRESULT = 0x%08x", result);
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try this. Can you include the relevant headers includes etc. and a `main()` so that it's reproducible? Something like this `cl test.cpp /link winmm.lib user32.lib Kernel32.lib /subsystem:windows /entry:wmainCRTStartup` would be super useful for future reference / future readers.

Comment: Thank you very much for the update @RitaHanMSFT. We're close to the solution! There are still a few errors: `MyAudioSink` is not defined as a class, etc. Could you maybe include the full .cpp code? (or maybe paste it temporarily on https://paste.ee/ or similar), I'm struggling a little bit to compile it. PS: Here https://paste.ee/p/MA69P I tried to use 1) the C++ code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/capturing-a-stream   2) your second code block  3) your third code block ("UPDATE").

Comment: @Basj Please check my update #2 for the full .cpp code. Use it just as a reference because it is not ready for a productive environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RitaHanMSFT, I'll try this as soon as possible!

Comment: Thanks, the recording works @RitaHanMSFT! (I'm still unable to open the .wav, probably a few errors in the headers, but I'll be able to check this part myself). There is still a small problem : when no sound is playing on the computer, no silence-frame is recorded, do you see how we could fix this ? Silence should be recorded if nothing uses the soundcard.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT, A very good example. In this example, data is written directly to the file. Is it possible to separate saving data to a buffer and writing data to a file? Save data to buffer. Then click on the button and write the data to the file?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: The above capturing is done in timer driven mode which consumes more cpu. Can anyone help me with an example with event driven mode and loopback recording using capture client?